# Using LINQ to check whether a field exists in a ternary operator in the select statement using C#'s Mongo Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

In MongoDB, there's a difference between checking for the existence of a field and checking if a field is null.

In the first query using the aggregation framework:

```js
collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { "isNull": { $eq: ["$InexistentField", null] } } }
])
```

This query is using the $eq operator within the $project stage to check if the specified field is equal to null. If the field exists and is null, the result will be true; otherwise, it will be false. If the field does not exist in the document, it will also return false because $eq with null returns false when the field is missing.

In the second query using the find method:

```js
collection.find(
        { "InexistentField" : { $eq : null } }] 
)
```

This query explicitly checks if the specified field is null and exists in the document. If the field is null or does not exist.

So, in summary, the difference lies in how the $eq operator behaves within the $project stage, where it considers a missing field as not equal to null, and the find method, where it explicitly checks for the existence of the field and whether it's null.

The problem that remains is that, when I write a LINQ expression with a ternary operator, the  aggregate pipeline is used, and the inexistence of the field is not properly checked. Consider this C# LINQ expression:

```cs
collection.AsQueryable()
   .Where(a => a.Id == "6310e8bdcb2982dee9af3924")
   .Select(a => new
       {
            Test = a.InexistentField is not null ? a.InexistentField.Property.Field : null
       });
```

This expression will generate this query for Mongo syntax:

```js
databaseName.CollectionName.Aggregate(
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "_id": ObjectId("6310e8bdcb2982dee9af3924")
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "Teste": {
                "$cond": {
                    "if": {
                        "$ne": [
                            "$InexistentField",
                            null
                        ]
                    },
                    "then": "$InexistentField.Property.Field",
                    "else": null
                }
            },
            "_id": 0
        }
    }
]
```

Is there a way to check the field existence within the projection, considering the native use of LINQ to generate the query expression?